# Rollback Transaction In Nested For Each Loops

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, try-catch

```
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
            //First 
            $id = DB::connection('otherDB')->table('HEAD')->insertGetId(['val' => $val]);
            foreach ($detail as $key => $valDetail) {
            // Second
                DB::connection('otherDB')->table('DETAIL')->insert(['head_id' => $id]);
            }
            // Third 
            MyTable::where('val', $val->id)->update(['status' => 1]);
        }
        DB::commit();
        return 'Success';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return 'Not Success';
    }
```

Hi, I am a beginner. Here I have 3 transactions, my goals are when every one of them does an error then all transaction should be doing a rollback. My recent result is when `//Second` transaction got errors the `//First` transaction and some `//Second` not rollbacked. I already try set `trycatch` inside the second loops, but still not getting the expecting result.

Comment: you should also use DB::connection on beginTransction and commit also rollback

Comment: With your beginTransaction, commit, and rollback statements, you're running them on the default connection, but all of your inserts are on the otherDB connection. You need to do the transaction statements on both connections so everything gets rolled back

Comment: Ah, I see. So there is nothing wrong with the try-catch and foreach model right? Thank you before.